# Don't the Planeswalkers in Commander 2014 that say they can be your Commander contradict the fact the Commanders have to be legendary creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-planeswalkers

[Ob Nixilis of the Black Oath](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ob%20Nixilis%20of%20the%20Black%20Oath) and the other Commanders in Commander 2014 say they can be your Commander. Doesn't that contradict the rule that Commanders can only be Legendary Creatures?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The very first of Magic's Golden Rules:

> 101.1. Whenever a card’s text directly contradicts these rules, the card takes precedence. The card overrides only the rule that applies to that specific situation. The only exception is that a player can concede the game at any time (see rule 104.3a).

So yes, they contradict, and it's fine. And this isn't really unusual; tons and tons of cards have text that effectively says "now the rules work a little differently, and here's how." For an extreme example, the rules say you lose the game when you're reduced to 0 or less life, but [Platinum Angel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Platinum%20Angel) says you can't lose the game, and it takes precedence.

Answer (score 2):

[*Ob Nixilis wasn't Legendary at the time this answer was written, but every Planeswalker was subsequently made Legendary. The question and answers are still pertinent because Ob Nixilis is still not a creature.*]

Yes<sup>[1]</sup>. Commanders are normally Legendary Creatures, and Ob Nixilis is neither Legendary nor a Creature.

> 903.1. In the Commander variant, each deck is led by a legendary creature designated as that deck’s commander. [...]

But that's fine because of the first Golden Rule of Magic:

> 101.1. Whenever a card’s text directly contradicts these rules, the card takes precedence. The card overrides only the rule that applies to that specific situation. The only exception is that a player can concede the game at any time (see rule 104.3a).

---

1. If it didn't, there would be no reason to put that ability on the card.

Comment: Can I suggest updating the first line (after the italics) to say "and Ob Nixilis is not a Creature."? That renders the italic section unnecessary and brings the answer fully up to date.